# Autorotate: View height modified after return to original rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios

Pretty self explanatory, see this image:

[image: Before/After Autorotation]

Steps to reproduce:

1. "Before" marks the view position in portrait orientation prior to autorotation.
2. Rotate the device to landscape.
3. Rotate back to portrait. "After" shows the view position after this return to portrait.

It appears that the height of the container view has been increased. Has anyone experienced this before? I'm sure there is some obscure setting that is slightly off.

Comment: did u try resetting your frame to the very first frame when are in step 3?

Comment: Is this on the iPhone 5 by any chance?

Comment: @JaySlupesky, yes this is on the iPhone 5. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @tiguero, I'd rather not do that since it completely removes the usefulness of the autoresizing mask.

Comment: which autoresizingMask did u use?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've set auto resizing masks correctly? Maybe that's the issue

Comment: If it were an autoresizing mask issue, the initial portrait landscape would be messed up too. What I have here are two different frames for the same orientation after autorotation.

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments that this is happening on the iPhone 5. I had some problems positioning views on the iPhone 5, and these issues could not be fixed with autoResizingMask no matter what setting I tried.  I eventually solved the problem by adding these two lines of code in viewDidLoad:

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
[self.view setFrame:[screen applicationFrame]];
```

Since your problem is on a rotation, you probably need these lines to be executed upon rotation rather than in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Sorry, I misled you. It is happening on the iPhone 5, but it is not limited to iPhone 5. It also happens on the 3.5" screens.